# Socketio event triggered inside of useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, socket.io

I am trying to use socketio and socketio-client for a real time chat app. But, I am having understanding how to go about implmenting it. I have the following function, which is triggered when a user has finished typing and presses the send button.The "send-new-message" event gets triggered well as I can see,the console log statement printed out from the backend code, but the event "new-message-received" isn't seen to be triggered in my frontend code even though the response.status is 200. What could be happenning here? how could I make sure that when I send new message is sent, both the send and receive events are triggered?

```
const handleNewMessage = async()=>{
        const newMessage = {
            sent_from:currentuser._id ,
            sent_to: itemOwnerId || item.second_person._id,
            time_stamp: new Date(),
            message: message,
        }
        socket.emit("send-new-message",newMessage)
        setMessage("")
        try{
            const response = await fetch("http://10.0.2.2:4000/sendNewMessageWithItems",{
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                newMessage
            }),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json"
            }

            })
            const result = await response.json()
            
            if(response.status === 200){
                socket.on("new-message-received",()=>{
                    setConversations(prev=>[...prev,result?.message])
                  })
            } else{
                console.log("Error saving the data on mongodb")
            }
        } catch(error){
            console.log("There is an error sendinga message????")
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

And the backend code that recieves and emits events is:

```
socket.on("send-new-message",(data)=>{
    console.log("A new messagefrom frontend in the socket",data)
    socket.emit("new-message-received")
  })
```

1. I saw some people suggesting to use useEffect with an empty dependency array like

```
useEffect(()=>{
socket.on("new-message-received",()=>{setConversations(prev=>[...prev,result?.message])})
         },[])
```

but I am not sure how it would work? I thought empty array dependency useEffect will only run once and the message sent after the first render won't be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

From Front-end (sender) :

```
const sendMsg = () => {
  socket.emit("send-new-message", {...msg});
}
```

Back end (Receiver) :

```
socket.on("send-new-message", (msg) => {
  ...do what you want
  socket.emit("reply-message", {...msg});
});
```

Again front end (receiver)

```
useEffect(() => {
  socket.on("reply-message", (msg) => {
    ...do what you want
  })
},[]);
```

Socket is not a restful api, it doesn't work as a give and take.

Comment: so if i use useEffect to accept reply-message event, will it even get excuted after the first render as the useEffect has an empty array dependency and according to react's official documentation, useEffects with empty array dependency run only once during the first render?

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that socket.on is like event listener. Once you enroll the listener it will be activated when the event triggered. So, you enroll the socket.on once, it will receive msg from server until you destroy the socket connection.